# How to name a downloaded data: file?

Tags: java, html

I'm creating a fantastic HTML editor. I haven't thought about the title, so it's gonna be "HTML Editor." The input (in the code below) is to name the file. *how could I name a file using the HTML's JavaScript components?* Is there anything wrong with the code, or what?

```
<input id="title" required placeholder="File Name" title="Please fill this space up, and don't include symbols.">
<a download href="data:text/html;utf-8,(contents)"> <button>Download File</button> </a>
```

The downloading part is great and all, and I'm glad to say it's working, but... the name "download" is pretty irritating. Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the download attribute to your filename.

```html
<a download="filename.jpg" ... />
```